# Constructor undefined, even though clearly imported?

Tags: java, timer, undefined

So I'm getting experience on this stuff little by little, but this problem seems so... weird, and almost unfair, that I don't know what to do. To explain, here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.swing.Timer; //I import the Timer class here, it is accepted
import javax.vecmath.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.behaviors.keyboard.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.behaviors.vp.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;

public class Scene extends BranchGroup {
public Scene () {

Transform3D translate = new Transform3D ();
translate.setTranslation (new Vector3d (0f, 0f, -10.f));
TransformGroup objTranslate = new TransformGroup (translate);
this.addChild (objTranslate);

Box box = new Box (0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, new Appearance());
objTranslate.addChild (box);

javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(5, this); //error message "The constructor Timer(int, Scene) is undefined"
timer.start();
}
}
```

Don't pay too much attention to the biggest part of the code, it is still a draft, will be refined later. The problem is with the timer, which always returns `The constructor Timer(int, Scene) is undefined`. I've added as much imports as I could, defined as clearly as possible in which import the Timer class was, etc. `timer.start()` works fine, so I suppose the class is recognised anyway. But the program won't run, because it's undefined. Even though imported. And I have no idea why.

Would one of you have an idea, or would be able to explain what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: "Don't pay too much attention to the biggest part of the code, it is still a draft" - in future, please provide short but complete examples which *only* contain code which is relevant to the question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Yes, I figured once re-reading it, just shortened it (easier now that I know where the problem was), sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Scene` class is not implementing `ActionListener`. See <del>[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)</del> [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

In other words, the `Timer` class does not have a constructor that takes an `int` and a `Scene` or `BranchGroup`. It only has a constructor that takes an `int` and an `ActionListener`.